# History of full retirement age: when were there policy changes?

Tags: united-states, retirement, benefits, social-security

The **full retirement age** is the age at which at which a person may first become entitled to full or unreduced retirement benefits. On the webpage of the Social Security Administration (http://www.socialsecurity.gov/retire2/agereduction.htm) an overview is given of the full retirement age by the year of birth.

My question is whether this table has been changed over the last decades and if so when and what is the name of the policy change (so I can look it up).

Thank you!

Comment: Try looking up FICA legislation changes

Answer (score 2):

Full retirement age was 65 in the [original 1935 legislation](http://www.socialsecurity.gov/history/35actii.html#Old-Benefit).

[A 1983 amendment](http://www.ssa.gov/pressoffice/IncRetAge.html) to this legislation increased the full retirement age as follows:

```
Year of Birth       Full Retirement Age
---------------------------------------
1937 and earlier    65 yrs
1938                65 yrs  2 mos
1939                65 yrs  4 mos
1940                65 yrs  6 mos
1941                65 yrs  8 mos
1942                65 yrs 10 mos
1943 through 1954   66 yrs 
1955                66 yrs  2 mos
1956                66 yrs  4 mos
1957                66 yrs  6 mos
1958                66 yrs  8 mos
1959                66 yrs 10 mos
1960 and later      67 yrs
```

Comment: Did you know this, or are you good at search engines?  Either way, nice answer.

Comment: Ha, no, didn't know it, but I don't think there have been too many changes yet.  The amendment is almost 30 years old, and it's still being listed as current on SSN.gov.